# shell backup script, missing `]`

Tags: shell, shell-script, control-flow

I'm putting together a simple backup script that will tar contents of a folder, then move that file to a backup server.  The script makes sure that the tar file exists and is not zero bytes before moving around.

The problem is that the script is dying on one of the IF lines

```
if [ -f /www/archives/pdf/pdf_201207021048.tar && 11294720 -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "tar file exists and is greater than 0 bytes."
else
    echo "tar file does not exist or is zero bytes"
fi
```

The error in the console is:

```
./backup_pdf.sh: line 49: [: missing `]'
```

Line 49 is the if statement above.

The script is successfully verified with

```
sh -n backup.sh
```

What's wrong that `sh` is seeing a missing ']', yet it passes the syntax check?

Comment: If you intend to use `bash`, you should use `[[`, not `[`.  Only use `[` if you are scripting for POSIX `sh`.  The [Bash FAQ 31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) explains the difference from `[` and `test`.  `[[` is much safer and more powerful.  It's also part of `bash` syntax, whereas `[` is a command and not syntax, so `bash -n` can't tell the difference between `[ invalid arg` and `echo invalid arg`.

Comment: I've incorrectly labeled my question.   I'm using sh.  Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `&&` is not a valid operator for `[`. It needs `-a` instead, or `[ condition ] && [ other_condition ]`.

`&&` is a [separator](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_03) (as is `;`, `||`, `&` and `\n`) in a posix shell. It sees the statement `[ -f www/archives/pdf/pdf_201207021048.tar`; the statement ends becaues there is a `&&`, then there is another statement (which also would cause an error if it got to it) that looks like `11294720 -gt 0 ]`, and that statement is terminated with `;`.

Comment: Any idea why bash -n gave the script a pass?  Shouldn't it have identified the syntax error?

Comment: I've never seen the `-n` option for Bash. It's not in the GNU manual or the BSD manual.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4874883/721073

Comment: The only thing I can think is that `[` is not so much part of shell syntax, it's actually a program invocation (even though it's usually a program built in to the shell). I would imagine the `-n` doesn't give any guarantees about correct command invocation.

Comment: Ah, that `-n` is part of `set`; the shell will pass appropriate commandline switches through set.